# Joomla Meta Title "reset to default"

Tags: joomla, seo

I'm having trouble figuring out why the meta title of a website I'm managing comes up as "reset to default" on Google.

Please see below for screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MJNC.png

Answer (score 1):

Your SERP link looks fine when I search for it in Google (see below). So I think that you might be to fast and google didn´t updated the result.

[image]